# How can I get high-precision timestamps (better than 1s) with Samba?

Tags: samba, timestamps

I did a quick test and got the results below. What's with the horrible time resolution? Is there a way I can make it better?

```
creation
129971441605098285
mod
129971442166583272
a.ToFileTimeUtc()
129971442170000000
b.ToFileTimeUtc()
129971442170000000
```

The results of ToFileTimeUtc (which returns the number of 100ns ticks since Jan 1, 1601) show that the timestamps have been rounded to the nearest second, instead of being stored with their full precision.

I'm using Samba on Ubuntu. I grabbed the config file from somewhere. I'm transferring files to a NTFS filesystem mounted by Linux over samba

```
[global]
netbios name = toltec
workgroup = METRAN
security = user
wins support = yes
preferred master = yes
os level = 65


[homes]
comment = %u's Home Directory
browsable = no
read only = no
```

Comment: First off, we're not .Net programmers here. Having Googled it, it appears that 129971442170000000 is a count in 100ns ticks (WTF, Microsoft?), so 12997144217 seconds. But with a Jan 1 **1601** epoch. So, basically, you're asking how to get better than 1-second resolution with Samba?

Comment: Second, you need to tell us some detail about your Samba server. In particular, are you using ext3 or ext4 (or something else entirely)? Ext3 doesn't support subsecond timestamps. Ext4 does.

Comment: @derobert: ah sorry. Ok so its actually worse then you think. I subtracted the date from 129971441605098285 and 129971442170000000 which got me a 56.49 **seconds** difference. Thats nearly a minute off

Comment: Hmmm, is the clock on the server set correctly?

Comment: @derobert: That doesn't exactly matter. Look at all those zeros. Also its a VM and the time is correct

Comment: Well, the get more accurate than 1s, you need to use a filesystem that supports it—so far, you haven't said which filesystem you're using. Also, I think there may be Samba options to explicitly request less-accurate, but that'd probably get you to 2s accuracy (like FAT). To get a minute off, something weird is going on. Like a clock set wrong somewhere.

Comment: @derobert: Actually i did mention NTFS (last text paragraph) but yeah 1min is very weird/wrong

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, you have a NTFS volume mounted on an Ubuntu box (probably with ntfs-3g?) and you have Samba pointed to that? And then you're copying files from some other machine (Windows, I assume?) to that file share?

Comment: Also, to be sure, make sure that `dos filetime resolution` is turned *off* in your Samba config.

Comment: @derobert: I think i counted wrong. It looks like its one second off and one of my test was failing because maybe linux/windows rounding up/down differently

Comment: Ok. Looking again, you're right, it's definitely the nearest second. But its odd, and all the documentation for `dos filetime resolution` says it'd be even were that on. So,  I guess, I should ask: which versions of Ubuntu and Samba?

Comment: Nearest second is fine. Minute... really isn't. I am using `2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3` on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Odd. You should have full 100ns support, added in [Samba 3.5](http://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-3.5.0.html). We're sure you're getting 1s support now, right? Difference between mod and ToFileTimeUTC is 0.34s…

Comment: I don't actually mind although 100ns is really good. I'm not sure if this affects anything but the OS is using ext3 while the drive is NTFS mounted on /media/drive-Letter/. The ext3 may be tricking it as / and /media has a lower time resolution. But... i'd imagine it be on a file bases and completely ignore the root filesystem

Comment: Acutally—what happens if you log into the Ubuntu server, and `stat` one of the files on the NTFS drive? Do you get access/modify/change times with decimals, or are they always .000… at the end?

Comment: @derobert There are milliseconds (.123). In all the time (a, m,c). I see the file i modified has none tho (.000)

Comment: I suspect you've found a limit of NTFS support under Linux. When I Google around, I do find people talking about getting 100ns timestamps to work March of this year... so it may just not work. It'd probably work if you stored your files on ext4 instead, but I don't have a test environment set up where I can quickly test this (or the NTFS setup you're using). I guess I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the long comment chain, it appears that ntfs-3g (or possibly FUSE) doesn't fully support 100ns timestamps, or at least the version in Ubuntu 12.04 does not. There are [random forum threads](http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29218) that indicate FUSE 2.9 is required, but [Ubuntu 12.04 has 2.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/fuse).

Ubuntu 12.10 does have FUSE 2.9, but its not a long-term support release. So you probably don't want to upgrade to it.

Another alternative would be to switch to a filesystem that supports high-resolution timestamps in Ubuntu 12.04, such as ext4. Unless you plan on disconnecting the disk from the Samba server and connecting it to a Windows machine, this is probably a better choice than NTFS anyway, especially if you enable extended attributes in Samba.

Comment: There isn't anything on it so i'll grab 12.10 and give it a try.